# Purpose of 2nd order filter for processing temperature measurement

Tags: filter, c, algorithm

Please forgive me if this is a very basic or silly question but I would appreciate some help.
I'm working on someone else's code and have come across a few lines that have been described as a 2nd order filter. My background is not in electronics so I'm not really sure what a 2nd order filter is or what the code is trying to do. I'm wondering if someone can help explain the following code?

```
setpoint_error = temperature_setpoint * FILTER_TERM_A - high_resolution_temperature_setpoint;
filtered_setpoint_error = filtered_setpoint_error + (setpoint_error - filtered_setpoint_error) / FILTER_TERM_A;
high_resolution_temperature_setpoint = high_resolution_temperature_setpoint + filtered_setpoint_error / FILTER_TERM_B;
```

Many thanks for your help.

*** UPDATED ON 2018-09-18 ***

Below are some extra lines to help put the code above in context.

```
#define INITIAL_TEMPERATURE 80
#define TEMPERATURE_SCALE 100
#define FILTER_TERM_A 512
#define FILTER_TERM_B 1024

static int32_t high_resolution_temperature_setpoint = INITIAL_TEMPERATURE * TEMPERATURE_SCALE * FILTER_TERM_A;
static int32_t blown_air_temperature = 12 * TEMPERATURE_SCALE;
static int32_t blown_air_temperature_error = 0L;
static int32_t blown_air_kP = 2L;
static int32_t blown_air_kI = 100L;
static int32_t blown_air_PID_speed = 0L;

void temperature_100ms_task()
{
    static int32_t filtered_setpoint_error;
    static int32_t blown_air_integrator_value = 0L;
    int16_t temperature_setpoint = 100;
    int32_t setpoint_error;
    int32_t blown_air_extrapolation_offset = get_BA_extrap_offset();

    /* Code that I would appreciate help understanding */
    setpoint_error = temperature_setpoint * FILTER_TERM_A - high_resolution_temperature_setpoint;
    filtered_setpoint_error = filtered_setpoint_error + (setpoint_error - filtered_setpoint_error) / FILTER_TERM_A;
    high_resolution_temperature_setpoint = high_resolution_temperature_setpoint + filtered_setpoint_error / FILTER_TERM_B;

    /* PID control - using temperature to adjust fan speed */
    blown_air_temperature_error = blown_air_temperature + blown_air_extrapolation_offset - high_resolution_temperature_setpoint / FILTER_TERM_A;
    blown_air_integrator_value += blown_air_temperature_error * blown_air_kI;
    blown_air_PID_speed = blown_air_temperature_error * blown_air_kP + blown_air_integrator_value;
}
```

The code above has been extracted from a much larger file but hopefully enough has been included to put the first code block in context. Thanks again.

Comment: Looks like two moving average that are combined with different averaging time.

Comment: Peter, I'm pretty sure from looking at these three lines that the variables are not floating point but are, instead, some form of integer variable. Can you confirm this? (It would work otherwise, too, but I think the "struggles" I see suggest integers to me.)

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. I've added some more code to help put the first block of code in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By itself, the code you exhibit doesn't look like a 2nd order filter to me. At least not in the sense that this involves the unique behaviors associated with them: the ability to be under-damped, over-damped, or critically-damped; no more, no less.

Of course, if this is part of PID (or something similar) then you can have all three of those behaviors. But you don't show the rest of the code. Only those three lines. I don't want you to be confused by the idea that those three lines, by themselves, represent a 2nd order filter. However, if this is part of a PID control loop and an external ***plant*** under control, then of course it may be 2nd order behavior. But then that's a different question, too. These three lines by themselves aren't 2nd order.

What I see is something like this:

$$\begin{align*}
\Delta &= T_\text{SET} -\frac{\Sigma}{A}\tag{1}\\\\
\Sigma_y&=\frac{A-1}{A}\Sigma_y+\Delta\tag{2}\\\\
\Sigma&=\Sigma+\frac{\Sigma_y}{B}\tag{3}
\end{align*}$$

The first line is a simple temporary computation of an error term of some sort. (In this case, I can't say exactly why an accumulator itself is being directly applied in this differencing calculation. I can only take note of it.) Note also that I adjusted the use of the factor FILTER_TERM_A in the first equation. For now, I just wanted to focus on ***what*** is happening more than on the details of ***how*** it is happening.

The second line is an accumulator. Depending on the value of FILTER_TERM_A (above and hereinafter noted as simply \$A\$), this accumulator (or integrator) value may have no meaning at all. So for example, if \$A=1\$, then \$\Sigma_y=\Delta\$ and it doesn't accumulate anything. It's just the error, or \$\Delta\$. But as \$A\$ increases in value beyond \$1\$, the accumulator starts operating and has an increasing effect. The larger that \$A\$ becomes, the ***less*** impact \$\Delta\$ has on adjusting the *other* accumulator, \$\Sigma\$, and the ***more*** impact that accumulator \$\Sigma_y\$ has on it. This second equation, more than the others, points up the purpose of \$A\$.

The third line is most probably the global integrator variable. The value of FILTER_TERM_B (above and hereinafter noted as simply \$B\$) determines how much impact the overall error term has (where the error term may itself be strongly filtered, or not filtered at all, depending on \$A\$.) If \$B\$ is very large, then the PID integrator term barely moves, at all, and will not play a significant role in the closed loop control system behavior. However, if \$B\$ is small, then the PID integrator has a greater impact on what follows (in the code you didn't provide) and the overall closed loop control as a complete system.

My guess about the reason for multiplying by \$A\$ in your first line of code is more about the use of integer variables, than much else. Had floating point been in use, it would have been sufficient to create a multiplier out of \$\frac{A-1}{A}\$ and simply used that factor in the 2nd equation rather than go to the trouble they did. But it's just a guess, as you also didn't say anything about the variable declarations.

Comment: Many thanks jonk. This is very helpful. You are quite right that the code is part of PID (or PI to be accurate). I've added a bit more code to put the first block of code in context. Does the additional information help explain the purpose of the code?

Comment: @Peter Well, for one thing I fully expected to see an initializing statement, "high_resolution_temperature_setpoint =", that would multiply the setpoint by \$A\$. And it does. So that inference was right (had to be.) So was the one that suggested integer declarations/definitions, too. I'll have to spend more time... not sure when... to provide more. But I'm no longer sure what your questions are, now, either. You were discussing 3 lines. Now you've got a lot more. What I've already said about the 3 seems to be right. Is there more?

Comment: Thanks for taking another look at this. I supplied the extra code to allow you to confirm if your theory is correct or not. Sounds like it is - which is brilliant. I plan to go through the details of your answer and code tomorrow so I'll hopefully be able to accept your answer then. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again jonk. Took me a bit longer than expected to get my head round the code and filtering in general but your answer was very helpful. Thank you.